# Child process limit with os.fork() and recursive function

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is any good way to put a cap on the number of processes spawned by os.fork() in a recursive function? Say I would like a maximum of 30 processes running at the same time to make sure the system is not completely overloaded.

I am parsing a (text)file for paths containing files, these in turn could also contain references to files. My solution is to design a recursive function and employing os.fork() in an effort to "parallelize" the function.

```
def recursive_copying(file, target_path):
    newlines=[]
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:

            # If pattern matching a path is detected
            if re.match(pathpattern,line)
                file_line=line

                # Spawn new process and scan file for paths
                pid = os.fork()
                    if pid==0:
                        recursive_copying(file_line, target_path)
                        os._exit(0)
                    else:
                        processes.append(pid)

            # Perform operations on currently read file/line and save to new line
            newlines.append(modified_line)

    # Create new file with modified lines
    new_file=target_path_path+file.split("/")[-1]
    with open(new_file,'w+') as f:
        for i in newlines:
            f.write(i)

    # Wait for all children processes to close
    for i in processes:
        os.waitpid(i,0)
    return
```

Truthfully yours,
Regretful

Comment: No, it's entirely up to you.  Maybe you need to use the `multiprocessing` module instead, where you can launch processes from a pool.

Comment: @TimRoberts Alright, I liked the simplicity of os.fork() but I will look into the multiprocessing module.

Comment: As @TimRoberts has rightly said, multiprocessing is the way to go here. Also worth noting that when using a multiprocessing pool (my personal preference being concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) you can constrain the pool size. I would also suggest that unless you have 30 or more CPU cores available, setting the pool size to that value may not give optimal results

Comment: And here I was hoping that this question would generate a heated discussion in the answers field :)
Yes I am wary of keeping the number of processes below the number of CPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the only way I have managed to pull it off is like this:

I am collecting all children processes created by the parent using shell commands:

```py
p4=subprocess.Popen("pgrep -P " + str(motherpid), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
p4.wait()
all_children=p4.communicate()[0].split('\n')
```

I use this list of child processes to find out how many are active (not defunct)

```py
def activeProcesses():
    p4=subprocess.Popen("pgrep -P " + str(motherpid), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    p4.wait()
    all_children=p4.communicate()[0].split('\n')
    all_children.remove('')
    all_children_static=all_children[:]
    for i in all_children_static:
        if not os.kill(int(i),0):
            all_children.remove(i)
    return all_children
```

A waiter function is used in the parent process but for children I let them continue without forking to make sure that they actually close their recursions.

```py
def processWaiter(limit):
    while len(activeProcesses()) >= limit:
        time.sleep(0.1) 
    return
```

The code will then look like this:

```py
def recursive_copying(file, target_path):
    newlines=[]
    processlimit=30
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:

            # If pattern matching a path is detected
            if re.match(pathpattern,line)
                file_line=line

                # If we are in main/parent process wait until 
                # amounts of processes allow forking
                if os.getpid() == parentpid:
                   processWaiter(processlimit)

                # If below active process limit -> fork
                if activeProcesses() < processlimit:
                    # Spawn new process and scan file for paths
                    pid = os.fork()
                        if pid==0:
                            recursive_copying(file_line, target_path)
                            os._exit(0)
                        else:
                            processes.append(pid)
                else:
                    recursive_copying(file_line, target_path)

            # Perform operations on currently read file/line and save to new line
            newlines.append(modified_line)

    # Create new file with modified lines
    new_file=target_path_path+file.split("/")[-1]
    with open(new_file,'w+') as f:
        for i in newlines:
            f.write(i)

    # Wait for all children processes to close
    for i in processes:
        os.waitpid(i,0)
    return

def activeProcesses():
    p4=subprocess.Popen("pgrep -P " + str(motherpid), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    p4.wait()
    all_children=p4.communicate()[0].split('\n')
    all_children.remove('')
    all_children_static=all_children[:]
    for i in all_children_static:
        if not os.kill(int(i),0):
            all_children.remove(i)
    return all_children

def processWaiter(limit):
    while len(activeProcesses()) >= limit:
        time.sleep(0.1) 
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startfile=sys.argv[1]
    target=sys.argv[2]
    motherpid=os.getpid()
    recursive_copying(startfile,target)
```

Perhaps it would be better to use the `multiprocessing` module but I really wanted to see if it was possible to do it in this sticks and stones way.